# Mi archivo CSV tiene 13 columnas pero python solo considera 1 columna

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Estoy trabajando con una base de datos CSV que tiene 391x13, sin embargo al ejecutar el código en python, la consola reconoce 391 filas y 1 columna. Esto es un problema ya que después intento definir las variables y obtengo error porque no coinciden las dimensiones. El código es el siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:/df.csv",
                 header=None, encoding = 'unicode_escape',
                 sep="delimiter", engine='python', index_col=None)
```

La salida:

```
389  ### - ###;166+ A###;37;1--1;166;##...
390  ### - ###;159+ ###;37;1...

[391 rows x 1 columns]
```

Cada `;` representa el espacio entre las columnas que deberían ser 13 y no 1 como se ve arriba. He probado con modificar los parametros `sep` e `index_col` pero sin resultado.

Espero que se haya entendido y si alguien sabe como puedo resolver esto se lo agardecería mucho. Saludos

Comment: Por defecto pandas espera que el separador de columnas sea la coma. Si es otra cosa, al no encontrar ninguna coma, considera todo una sola columna. En tu caso, encima, has puesto `sep="delimiter"`, con lo que ahora considera que el separador sea la palabra `"delimiter"`, que tampoco aparece

Comment: CUando digas que "probaste modificar el parámetro x", procura indicar qué valores usaste. Cambiar por cambiar no va a resolver el problema :)

Comment: Alfabravo tu comentario tampoco resolvió mi problema saludos

Answer (score 2):

El argumento posicional del método `read_csv` `sep="delimiter"` debes cambiarlo por el caracter separador textual, en tu caso debe ser `sep=";"`.

Cámbialo y avisa si te resulta :).

Comment: funcionó, muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto:

```
df=pd.read_csv('archivo.csv', sep=';', encoding='latin-1')
```